# differenciate Swipe and tap getsures android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, gesturedetector

I'm trying to make note app and have some problems : 
I have custom Edittext inside custom LinearLayout and trying to handle swipe on Edittext. I'm using this solution of swipe recognition [OnSwipeTouchListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures) and it works perfect, until I tap on edittext (in witch case edittext doesn't get focus). I set OnSwipeTouchListener as edittext.ontouchlistener 
    public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context c) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(c, new GestureListener());
}

public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;


    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e){
        print(211212, "singleTap shemovida");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    // Determines the fling velocity and then fires the appropriate swipe event accordingly
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        print(21512512, "fling");
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeDown();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeUp();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

static void print(int line, String st){
    PRINT.print("ONSwipeTouchListener", line, st);
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeUp() {
}

public void onSwipeDown() {
}
```

and I set it to edittext

```
    void addTextView(){
    _myText = new CustomEditText(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    _myText.setLayoutParams(params);
    _myText.setId(getEditTextId());
    addView(_myText);
    _myText.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getContext()) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeDown() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            CustomEditTextWithCheckbox.this.onSwipeLeft();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeUp() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            CustomEditTextWithCheckbox.this.onSwipeRight();
        }
    });
}
```

but as I guess in OnSwipeTouchListener.OnTouch always returns true and so edittext does not get focus. 
I have also tryed to change onTouch

```
 public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
   gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    return false;
}
```

and it works, but still problem is that on swipe edittext gets focus when i want to swipe,  And I understand why its working like that. But i need that if user does not swipe than on touch should return false, else true.
Can anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution for my question [here](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss)
u need to change a bit SwipeDismissTouchListener this way

```
public class SwipeDismissTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private int mSlop;
private int mMinFlingVelocity;
private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
private long mAnimationTime;

// Fixed properties
private CustomEditTextWithCheckbox mView;
private DismissCallbacks mCallbacks;
private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero

// Transient properties
private float mDownX;
private float mDownY;
private boolean mSwiping;
private int mSwipingSlop;
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
private float mTranslationX;

public interface DismissCallbacks {
    boolean canDismiss();
    void onDismiss(View view);
}

public SwipeDismissTouchListener(CustomEditTextWithCheckbox view, DismissCallbacks callbacks) {
    ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(view.getContext());
    mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity() * 16;
    mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
    mAnimationTime = view.getContext().getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
    mView = view;
    mCallbacks = callbacks;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    // offset because the view is translated during swipe
    motionEvent.offsetLocation(mTranslationX, 0);

    if (mViewWidth < 2) {
        mViewWidth = mView.getWidth();
    }

    switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            // TODO: ensure this is a finger, and set a flag
            mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            mDownY = motionEvent.getRawY();
            if (mCallbacks.canDismiss()) {
                mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            }
            return false;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
            float velocityX = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity();
            float absVelocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
            float absVelocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
            boolean dismissRight = false;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mViewWidth / 2 && mSwiping) {
                dismissRight = deltaX > 0;
            } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= absVelocityX && absVelocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity
                    && absVelocityY < absVelocityX
                    && absVelocityY < absVelocityX && mSwiping) {
                dismissRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
            }
            if (dismissRight) {
               mView.onSwipeRight();
            } else if (mSwiping) {
               mView.onSwipeLeft();
            }
            mVelocityTracker.recycle();
            mVelocityTracker = null;
            mTranslationX = 0;
            mDownX = 0;
            mDownY = 0;
            mSwiping = false;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            mVelocityTracker.recycle();
            mVelocityTracker = null;
            mTranslationX = 0;
            mDownX = 0;
            mDownY = 0;
            mSwiping = false;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            float deltaY = motionEvent.getRawY() - mDownY;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop && Math.abs(deltaY) < Math.abs(deltaX) / 2) {
                mSwiping = true;
                mSwipingSlop = (deltaX > 0 ? mSlop : -mSlop);
                mView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
                cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL |
                        (motionEvent.getActionIndex() <<
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                mView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                cancelEvent.recycle();
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

doint this way it works perfectly, hope it will be helpfull